# node-red - Globally available connection pools

Tags: node.js, postgresql, redis, connection-pooling, node-red

I have a requirement to connect to Redis and PostgreSQL databases. For performance reasons, I need to be able to connect to these databases with a connection pool. There are some packages for connection pool e.g. Redis [redis-connection-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-connection-pool), [node-redis-connection-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redis-connection-pool) and Postgres[node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling). These work well individually.

How do I make them work across a Node-RED instance? Can I set-up a script that runs at Node-RED start-up which then 'exports' the pool object to any node that could 'require' it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would have to look at how the available node-red nodes for Redis and Postgres were written and then modify them if needed.

A lot of nodes already have the concept of shared config nodes which hold a connection so they may already have a point to anchor a pool.